# SPARQL query without URI

Tags: sparql, rdf, jena, semantic-web

I am writing a SPARQL query if I write `<http://www.XXXX.eu/bd/motility` then it work but if I write `bd:motility` then it giving no results. The property name is motility, I have uploaded the data in Jena Fuseki server.

```
PREFIX bd: <http://www.XXXX.eu/bd/#> 

SELECT ?strains
WHERE {
     ?strains <http://www.XXXX.eu/bd/motility> "1"^^xsd:boolean .

 } LIMIT 5
```

What is the logical or syntax mistake behind it?

Comment: Remove `#` in the `bd:` prefix decrlaration.

Comment: @StanislavKralin It worked, thanks, what is the logic of this?

Comment: Consider `:` in prefixed URL as just concatenation.  Then `bd:motility` is abbreviation for `http://www.XXXX.eu/bd/#motility`, which is not the same as `http://www.XXXX.eu/bd/motility`. See also https://www.w3.org/wiki/HashVsSlash.